# Loading login_form View with Tank Auth Giving PHP Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I'm trying to add the login_form from Tank_auth view into my HTML template.

When I do so, it returns a few errors regarding missing variables, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $topbar['account'] = $this->load->view('auth/login_form');
    $data['topbar'] = $topbar;
    $this->load->view('main_template', $data);
}
```

Main template looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head><?php echo $template['head'] ?></head>
<body>
    <div id="topbar"><?php echo $topbar['account'] ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I'm receiving when loading the page is the following:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: show_captcha
>
> Filename: auth/login_form.php
>
> Line Number: 47

In addition, I'm receiving identical errors for:

`Undefined variable: login_by_username`

Heres the login form (untouched...default tank_auth form)

```
<?php
$login = array(
    'name'  => 'login',
    'id'    => 'login',
    'value' => set_value('login'),
    'maxlength' => 80,
    'size'  => 30,
);
if ($login_by_username AND $login_by_email) {
    $login_label = 'Email or login';
} else if ($login_by_username) {
    $login_label = 'Login';
} else {
    $login_label = 'Email';
}
$password = array(
    'name'  => 'password',
    'id'    => 'password',
    'size'  => 30,
);
$remember = array(
    'name'  => 'remember',
    'id'    => 'remember',
    'value' => 1,
    'checked'   => set_value('remember'),
    'style' => 'margin:0;padding:0',
);
$captcha = array(
    'name'  => 'captcha',
    'id'    => 'captcha',
    'maxlength' => 8,
);
?>
<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_label($login_label, $login['id']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input($login); ?></td>
        <td style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error($login['name']); ?><?php echo isset($errors[$login['name']])?$errors[$login['name']]:''; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_label('Password', $password['id']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_password($password); ?></td>
        <td style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error($password['name']); ?><?php echo isset($errors[$password['name']])?$errors[$password['name']]:''; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php if ($show_captcha) {
        if ($use_recaptcha) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA</a>
            <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
            <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">Get an image CAPTCHA</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above</div>
            <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear</div>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" /></td>
        <td style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error('recaptcha_response_field'); ?></td>
        <?php echo $recaptcha_html; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <p>Enter the code exactly as it appears:</p>
            <?php echo $captcha_html; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_label('Confirmation Code', $captcha['id']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input($captcha); ?></td>
        <td style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error($captcha['name']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    } ?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <?php echo form_checkbox($remember); ?>
            <?php echo form_label('Remember me', $remember['id']); ?>
            <?php echo anchor('/auth/forgot_password/', 'Forgot password'); ?>
            <?php if ($this->config->item('allow_registration', 'tank_auth')) echo anchor('/auth/register/', 'Register'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Let me in'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Hopefully someone is familiar with Tank Auth and can solve this problem easily.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's something with tank_auth conflicting with your code, despite the fact I didn't have any problems with clean installs of it, are you using captcha functionality and are your users authorized via email or username?

Comment: i use the default functionality, which means they should be authorized through both e-mail or username (whichever they decide to type in).  And yes, currently using captcha functionality(default).  This is a very fresh install, of CI and Tank Auth.  On my other pages, I simply linked directly to the controller URI from auth/login.  But this time, i'd like to simply add it to my page

Comment: One thing i tried, and seemed be successful, was to simply change Tank_Auths controller into a model, and call it through that.  No problems so far.

Comment: you need to show us your login_form. Also - tank_auth comes with a default auth.php file - you should look at that - sounds like you are not pre-loading some required information

Comment: @TheShiftExchange added the login_form code.  The auth.php file youre referring to... believe is a controller.  And as far as I could figure, you can't (or should not) call a controller function from another controller.  Thats why I just turned all the functions in a model.

Comment: So. It turns out that the variables i was missing were generated in the auth.php controller, which calls the login_form.php view.  Converting auth.php to a model worked fine.  Though im not sure if its the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first please check auth controller how they using login and passing show_captcha to you login_form view, you are not passing show_captcha to login_view

```
    $login_data['login_by_username'] = ($this->config->item('login_by_username','tank_auth') AND $this->config->item('use_username','tank_auth'));
    $login_data['login_by_email'] = $this->config->item('login_by_email', 'tank_auth');

    $login_data['show_captcha']  = FALSE

    $topbar['account'] = $this->load->view('auth/login_form',$login_data);
    $data['topbar'] = $topbar;
    $this->load->view('main_template', $data);
```

it will not show captcha, but i suggest you to follow login method of thank auth's auth controller